# iOS Expansion. You've already purchased this in-app purchase but it hasn't been downloaded

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented expantion feature in my iOS app. But I have one problem. After I call:

```
[[SKPAymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

and connection was lost before:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

Than in next time when I want to addPayment, message appears:
"You've already purchased this in-app purchase but it hasn't been downloaded"

Does anybody have any ideas?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to give more details on the app you are developing. What kind of products you are selling? is it require download? Please put in more codes so that is easier for others who willing to help to guess what you are developing and provide reference accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found solution for this problem. Next time I start application I receive my "unfinished" transaction in the payment queue. I moved my

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

to the mthod didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate